# Python pandas plotting Quarter values

Tags: python, pandas, plot

Receiving error: Axis must have `freq` set to convert to Periods
when trying to plot from a DataFrame with index values like 2006Q1

```
 df1 = SalesReport[['Time','Product1','Product2','Product3']]
 df1['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Time'], format='%d/%m/%y')
 df1 = df1.set_index('Time')
 df1.index = df1.index.to_period("Q")
```

as a result got a data in a needed format and happy with it:

```
        Product1   Product2   Product3
Time                                   
2005Q4  5023203.0  6718023.0  3964175.0
2006Q1  5048207.0  6735528.0  3987653.0
2006Q2  5061266.0  6742690.0  4007992.0
```

But now when I'm trying to plot:

```
plt.plot(df1)
plt.show()
```

receive an error: Axis must have `freq` set to convert to Periods

What is the correct way of plotting such type of dataFrame?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know the reasons why it does not work using `plt.plot()` but you can try to plot with `pandas`'s `plot` function, which also uses matplotlib... I am using Python 3 and pandas 0.20

```
df.plot()
```

[image]

Reference

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html